# Factoring for exponents

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, trigonometry, factorization

How can I factorise into powers of integer exponents?

An expression such as,

```
factored = 
  2^(-j - k) E^(-y/t) 
    (I (E^(-I y w) - E^(I y w)))^k (E^(-I y w) + E^(I y w))^j
```

can be expressed as,

```
unfactored = 
  I^k 2^(-j - k) E^(-y/t - I j y w - I k y w) 
    (1 - E^(2 I y w))^k (1 + E^(2 I y w))^j
```

My aim is to reduce `unfactored` to $e^{-y/t}\cos^j (y\,w)\sin^k (y\,w)$, but Mathematica doesn't seem to be able to do this unless the expression is factorised in terms of `j, k` as in `factored`

#### Attempts

- `Collect[unfactored,  {E^(y w), E^(- y w)}]` and variants
- `ExpToTrig[unfactored] // FullSimplify` and variants

#### Working Example *and a sanity check!*

```
ExpToTrig[
  (I/2 E^(-I y w) (1 - E^(2 I y w)))^k 
    (1/2 E^(-I y w) (1 + E^(2 I y w)))^j] // FullSimplify
```

gives,
$
\cos^j(y\,w) \sin ^k(y\,w)
$

Comment: Have you looked into `ComplexExpand[]`, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and it didn't really help. Should I explicitly specify somehow that $j,k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Did you try adjusting `TargetFunctions`?

Comment: I just cycled through the options in `TargetFunctions`, `{Re, Im}` half gets there but still can't get the proper form

Comment: I had `TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}` in mind...

Comment: see the edit it was the same anyway :(

Comment: Do `factored` and `unfactored` really represent the same quantity?

Comment: Yeah I actually brute forced the comparison by changing it one tiny bit at a time. I will post the forced method later today

Comment: I haven't posted the code I used as it is no longer needed but for completeness I had to proceed by adding only one variable with each evaluation to the bracketed `j,k` factors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered problems of this sort when deriving plasma dispersion relations with Mathematica.  The essence of the problem appears to be that `FullSimplify` does not have

```
tf[e_] := e //. 
    {Exp[z1_ - I z2_ z3_] (1 + Exp[2 I z3_])^z2_ -> Exp[z1] (Exp[-I z3] + Exp[I z3])^z2, 
     Exp[z1_ - I z2_ z3_] (1 - Exp[2 I z3_])^z2_ -> Exp[z1] (Exp[-I z3] - Exp[I z3])^z2}
```

among its `TransformationFunctions`.  Adding it solves the problem.

```
FullSimplify[unfactored, (j | k) ∈ Integers, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]

(* E^(-(y/t)) Cos[w y]^j Sin[w y]^k *)
```

Note that, if `j` and `k` were specific integers, `FullSimplify` together with `Expand` would be sufficient.  For instance,

```
FullSimplify[Expand[unfactored /. {j -> 3, k -> 4}]]

(*( E^(-(y/t)) Cos[w y]^3 Sin[w y]^4 *)
```

Comment: strange... If you use exactly the same expression but remove `-y/t` from the exponential then it fails. Is this because the rule explicitly references `Exp[z1]`? Just tested and confirmed that is the reason. Very informative answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane That right. If `z1` is zero, a different rule is needed, `tf[e_] := e //. {Exp[z1_ - I z2_ z3_] (1 + Exp[2 I z3_])^z2_ -> 
    Exp[z1] (Exp[-I z3] + Exp[I z3])^z2, Exp[-I z2_ z3_] (1 - Exp[2 I z3_])^z2_ -> (Exp[-I z3] - Exp[I z3])^ z2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unfactored /. 
  E^(a_ - I *p_* w y)*(1 + E^(2*I * w y))^p_ :> E^a*2*Cos[p w y]^p /. 
 E^(a_ - I *p_* w y)*(1 - E^(2*I * w y))^p_ :> -E^a*2*I*Sin[p w y]^p

(*  -I I^k 2^(2 - j - k) E^(-(y/t)) Cos[j w y]^j Sin[k w y]^k  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: can you briefly explain what the two pieces of notation: `/.` and `:>` are doing? Is this an in-line version of @bbgodfrey 's answer?

Comment: @Alexander McFarlane Just type `?/.`+Enter and `?:>`+Enter and you will have an explanation, and then click on the `>>` sign in its end to have details. It is more or less the same as in bbgodfrey answer, differing in fine details.